# Worklight CSS on Android doesn't find the images folder

Tags: android, css, image, background-image, ibm-mobilefirst

In my css I have a background-image like this:

```
    background-image:url("../images/klasExFoto.png") !important;
```

In the emulator and webbrowser it shows the image.
When I run it on an Android device it doesn't find the image in that folder.
When I set an image in HTML, it works fine.

```
    <img src="images/klasExFoto.png" />
```

Like this it works on both the browser and an Android device.

If I set the background-image without the "../", it doesn't work anymore on both Android and webbrowser.

How can I set the folder path on Android for CSS background-images?

I use Worklight 6.0.0.1.

My CSS:

```
    #AddClassForm_Foto{
        width:140px;
        height:140px;
        background-image:url("../images/klasExFoto.png") !important;
        border:doubles 1px #dedede;
    }
    .formItem{
        margin-top:16px;
    }
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="formItem">
    <label for="AddClassForm_Foto">Foto</label>
    <div id="AddClassForm_Foto"></div>
    </div>
```

I only see an image on the webbrowser, in Android it doesn't show up.

Comment: set the folder path as `images/klasExFoto.png` in your CSS background image. Because it will always go to search for the image into `images` folder only.

Comment: If I set it like that, it doesn't work on all devices.

Comment: Where have you kept your `images` folder ?

Comment: @GrlsHu "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.99.10.95:10080/Klappr/apps/services/preview/Klappr/common/1.0/default/css/images/klasExFoto.png"

I used the custom Worklight images folder.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention versions for anything.

I have the following in a WL 6.0.0.1 project:

```
img {

background-image:url("../images/icon.png")
}
```

And run the android environment on Android 4.1.2 and 4.3.  The background image shows up.

Either it is something specific to the versions of Worklight and Android that you are using, or something other than the relative path is the problem.

Comment: I edited the question with more information.
I use WL 6.0.0.1 and see no image.
why do you use a background-image on an img element?
@David

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is probably not a WL specific issue.  I would suggest you validate the final CSS file for syntax errors by passing it through a CSS linter (eg. http://csslint.net/).

As another test, move that rule to the very top of your CSS file and see if it makes a difference. Different renderers may be more tolerant of syntax errors.

Look at the final CSS in the android/native/assets/www/default/css/MyCss.css file for any obvious issues, when the CSS files are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my image had a capital K and the webbrowser didn't mind it, but Android did.

I replaced "../images/klasExFoto.png" with "../images/KlasExFoto.png" and now everything works again.